# SSIS- generate excel reports based on templates

Tags: c#, sql, excel, ssis

I have an excel report (tenplate) with 4 sheets and pivot tables.
The source is two sql tables and this report is connected to sql database using connection string.

I want to create a process in SSIS that for each month take these template report and create an new one with data from the tables updated.

Anyone has an idea how to do that?

I am trying to develop a process that creates a new excel report based on template in SSIS.